# Firebase can't store image form Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I want store image to Firebase across array. 
This is my html:

```
 <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">

    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpload()">Clikc</button>
```

This is my variable for image: `selectedFile = null;`

My method in component :

```
 onFileSelected(event) {

this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
console.log(this.selectedFile);


}



onUpload() {
    const fb = new FormData();
    fb.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)
    this.http.post('https://ng-recipe-.firebaseio.com/', fb).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
      }
    )
  }
```

I sent in the `Database` in Firebase and I have error :

```
POST https://ng-recipe-book-e.firebaseio.com/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Does somebody know how pass whole array with image on server.

I want sent this model with image on server:

```
import { ProductModel } from "./product.model";

export class CategoryModel {

public name: string;
public description: string;
public image: FormData = null;
public products?: ProductModel[];
public file: File;

constructor(name: string, desciption: string, image: FormData = null, products: ProductModel[], file: File) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desciption;
    this.image = image;
    this.products = products;
    this.file = file;
}

}
```